# When is it appropriate to re-assign a function argument or return a pointer to new memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

While looking at some functions of `<cstdio>`, I saw the function `fread` for reading files. From what I understand, the function just reads `size * count` bytes from `stream` and writes that same amount contiguously starting at the address stored by `ptr`.

```cpp
size_t fread (void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream );
```

In this case, the function `fread` happens to return the number of bytes read, but I'm curious about its secondary effects on `ptr`, which to me almost seems like a second or alternative output.

Specifically, in which cases is one of the following better practice than the other, and why?

```cpp
void function_modifying_parameter (int x, int &y /* or int *y */)
{
  y = 2 * x;
}
```

```cpp
int * function_returning_pointer (int x)
{
  return new int (2 * x);
}
```

I have thought about some possible advantages of each one myself. Here's what I think:

- Returning a pointer seems to allow enforcing `const` requirements, whereas a passed pointer or reference returns to its pre-call `const`ness after leaving the function, allowing the caller more freedom to manipulate the output.
- Passing a pointer or reference allows choosing to provide a heap or a stack variable at the user's discretion, but a fresh new pointer only makes sense to point to the heap, since the function's local scope will be destroyed post-call.
- To me, returning a pointer is more readable. In the simplest cases, passing an additional parameter by reference for output purposes increases header length. An array type, or another type that needs additional information to use, might require even more arguments.
- If a function will be called many times, and it is possible to re-assign a reference or pointer parameter over and over, repeatedly using a a variable can reduce the number of `delete` statements needed and bugs related to their misuse.

Mainly, I'm interested in what things one can do that the other one can't, as well as when one is better than the other, where the goal is to write more readable, useful, and/or efficient code.

Comment: this is opinion-based. Unless you have good reason, simply return `y` (no pointer!).

Comment: consider that you were looking at C functions and C has no references

Comment: Another point (mostly for pre-C++11) is efficiency: return by value might do extra copies.

Comment: fwiw, perhaps the analogous C++ method is [`std::istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read). I guess it takes a pointer not a reference, because it isnt actually modifying the buffer you pass, but only writing into it

Comment: i don't understand your edit. If `y` is passed as pointer that does not imply that `y` needs to be dynamically allocated or that `new` and `delete` are used. Using `new` / `delete` and passing reference or pointer are orthogonal issues

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I didn't intend to say that `y` must be dynamically allocated. One of my points in favor of passing pointers and references rather than returning them was that they can refer to stack memory, whereas new, returned pointers that would serve a similar purpose have to be made on the heap.

Comment: I did get mixed up! I meant to talk not just about passing references and returning pointers, but to to talk about passing both pointers and references as well as returning pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Of those two, the first is unambiguously better.

If you wanted to compare something more similar, it should be:

```
extern "C" size_t modifying_function(size_t s, char* buffer) noexcept {
    ...
}

std::string allocating_function() {
    ...
}
```

The first has the advantage of not allocating memory, nor using any complex types. As such, it will always succeed (even if just by returning a bigger size), and gives the caller leave to use his own buffer. It is ideal for cross-language use.

The second has the advantage of returning a type well-suited for working with, and taking care of all the details of buffer-management. Unfortunately, the buffer-management can fail.

As an aside, especially if the work done is more elaborate, and there might be bindings for other languages, it is not uncommon to have both the low-level function leaving buffer management to the caller, and some higher-level function using it and taking care of wrapping it in more semantic types while taking care of resource management.

```
auto allocating_function() {
    auto s = std::string().capacity();
    for (;;) {
        std::string r(s, '\0');
        s = modifying_function(r.size(), r.data());
        if (s > r.size())
            continue;
        r.resize(s);
        return r;
    }
}
```

Now there is also a variant to `allocating_function()` which *tries* to re-use a previously used buffer, as allocation and deallocation are generally expensive:

```
auto& reallocating_function(std::string& r) {
    for (;;) {
        auto s = modifying_function(r.size(), r.data());
        if (s <= r.size())
            break;
        r.resize(s);
    }
    r.resize(s);
    return r;
}
```

It is obviously a bit more cumbersome to use.